# Plot phylogenetic trees face to face with links in R

Tags: r, phylogeny

I would like to plot two phylogenies opposite each other in R using the `ape` package. One tree has 40 nodes and one has 26 nodes:

```
library(ape)
tree1 <- rtree(40)
tree2 <- rtree(26)
```

The `cophyloplot` function plots these face to face with specified links.

I'm having trouble specifying the links.

Note that in my actual `nexus` tree files, tip labels are text (and I'm unsure how to change these to numbers, if necessary...).

The links should be as follows:

If, in the `tree1` nexus file, the tip labels of the sequences are 1-40. In the `tree2` nexus file, tip labels are 1-26. Then links should be:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40)
b <- c(14,1,4,1,9,12,2,10,6,3,13,5,14,15,18,19,19,7,14,9,10,11,25,22,21,16,23,24,26,17,1,12,12,21,15,16,21,8,20,21) 
association <- cbind(a, b)
```

(i.e. sequence 1 in `tree1` is linked with sequence 14 in `tree2`)

So, I use something like this to plot the trees:

```
cophyloplot(tree1, tree2, assoc=association,length.line=4, space=28, gap=10, rotate=TRUE)
```

And calculate the distance matrix:

```
dist.topo(tree1, tree2, method = "PH85")
```

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To plot the trees, try this

```
library(ape)
set.seed(1)

# create trees
tree1 <- rtree(40)
tree2 <- rtree(26)

# modify tip labels
tree1$tip.label <- sub("t", "", tree1$tip.label, fixed = T)
tree2$tip.label <- sub("t", "", tree2$tip.label, fixed = T)

# create associations matrix 
a <- as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40))
b <- as.character(c(14,1,4,1,9,12,2,10,6,3,13,5,14,15,18,19,19,7,14,9,10,11,25,22,21,16,23,24,26,17,1,12,12,21,15,16,21,8,20,21)) 
association <- cbind(a, b)

# plot
cophyloplot(tree1, tree2, assoc = association, length.line = 4, space = 28, gap = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks!! I'm getting the following error: `Error in decx[i] <- strwidth(x$tip.label[lsa[x$tip.label == assoc[i, 1]]]) : 
  replacement has length zero` So I tried `tree1$tip.label<-(1:40)
tree2$tip.label<-(1:26)`

Comment: When I run your code @lukeA I get the same trees but it is unreadable and needs to be expanded.  How can I expand it to look like yours?

Answer (score 1):

The `cophyloplot` function does not require tip label indexing. One can refer to the taxa with their names. Note that lukeA's answer stores numbers from the associations as `character`. Transforming them to text that corresponds to tip labels and plotting the two trees shows the same result.

```
association <- apply(association, 2, function(x) sub("^","t", x))

head(association)
#      a    b    
# [1,] "t1" "t14"
# [2,] "t2" "t1" 
# [3,] "t3" "t4" 
# [4,] "t4" "t1" 
# [5,] "t5" "t9" 

cophyloplot(tree1, tree2, assoc=association, length.line=4, space=28, gap=3)
```

The order, in which the associations are listed in the matrix, is irrelevant. The best practice would be to import them from an external file with `read.table()`.